# Why is my FOREACH loop stopping after 3 iterations? (PHP & Stripe)

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, stripe-payments

My code is large as I am working on a subscription PHP plugin for WordPress. However, although most is done I now face a glitch that I can't fix. This is the flow:

1. User fills in the signup form with shipping, billing and account details
2. I create his account (WordPress)
3. Once confirmed, I call \Stripe\Customer::create() with his email and card details
4. Stripe creates the customer and sends it as JSON response
5. I convert the Stripe Customer Object into an array called $object (->__toArray( true )) and then insert each field into my database

This is where my foreach comes into play. I made an error_log( $object ) before the foreach just to make sure there was everything I need and it's correct.

```
    [26-Jan-2016 12:01:58 UTC] Array
    (
        [id] => cus_7n5hEVJs2btpg8
        [object] => customer
        [account_balance] => 0
        [created] => 1453809716
        [currency] => 
        [default_source] => card_17XVWCIh4e6dX4rQYJ8JzE7e
        [delinquent] => 
        [description] => 
        [discount] => 
        [email] => hello@xfsgfs.com
        [livemode] => 
        [metadata] => Array
            (
            )

        [shipping] => 
        [sources] => Array
            (
                [object] => list
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => card_17XVWCIh4e6dX4rQYJ8JzE7e
                                [object] => card
                                [address_city] => 
                                [address_country] => 
                                [address_line1] => 
                                [address_line1_check] => 
                                [address_line2] => 
                                [address_state] => 
                                [address_zip] => W12 8QQ
                                [address_zip_check] => pass
                                [brand] => Visa
                                [country] => US
                                [customer] => cus_7n5hEVJs2btpg8
                                [cvc_check] => pass
                                [dynamic_last4] => 
                                [exp_month] => 1
                                [exp_year] => 2019
                                [fingerprint] => FIYdIZ89jqCdZ9G4
                                [funding] => credit
                                [last4] => 4242
                                [metadata] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [name] => Lazhar Ich
                                [tokenization_method] => 
                            )

                    )

                [has_more] => 
                [total_count] => 1
                [url] => /v1/customers/cus_7n5hEVJs2btpg8/sources
            )

        [subscriptions] => Array
            (
                [object] => list
                [data] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [has_more] => 
                [total_count] => 0
                [url] => /v1/customers/cus_7n5hEVJs2btpg8/subscriptions
            )

    )
```

However, the foreach loop going through each of these $k/$v stops after two or three iterations and my actual page gives me a Chrome error message "err_empty_response.

```
[26-Jan-2016 11:58:02 UTC] id = cus_7n5diIO2wjeaYX
[26-Jan-2016 11:58:02 UTC] object = customer
```

My actual loop is like that:

```
    public function reconcile( $object = null, $action = null ) {

        $exists = $this->exists();

        if( $exists ) {

            if( !$object )
                $object = $this->retrieve();

            if( !is_array( $object ) && !($object instanceof stdClass) )
                $object = $object->__toArray( true );

            error_log( print_r( $object, true ) );

            foreach ( $object as $key => $value ) {

                error_log( $key . ' = ' . $this->formatvalue( $value, false, true ) );
                $this->$key = $this->formatvalue( $value, false, true );

            }

            error_log( 'update to be called next.' );
            $this->update();
        }
    }

    public function formatvalue( $value, $serialize = true, $nulltoemptystring = false ) {

        if( !isset( $value ) )
            return $nulltoemptystring ? '' : null;

        elseif( is_int( $value ) && $value == '0' )
            return 0;   

        elseif( is_array( $value ) )
            return $serialize ? serialize( $value ) : $value;

        elseif( is_bool( $value ) )
            return $value ? 1 : 0;

        elseif( trim( $value ) === '' )
            return '';

        else
            return $value;
    }
```

I am very confused as in why it stops at object (just a string) or account_balance (just an int, usually 0) and never goes to created and the rest.

**EDIT: here is a screenshot of my entire error_log**
[image: screenshot of error_log]

**EDIT2: to make sure it is not about these specific array keys or values, I changed the code and the same behaviour happens, it stops after a couple of iterations**

```
[26-Jan-2016 13:02:13 UTC] id = (string) cus_7n6fFVw0w3awiy
[26-Jan-2016 13:02:13 UTC] created = (integer) 1453813333
```

Results from:

```
    if( $key != 'object' && $key != 'account_balance' ) {
        $v = $this->formatvalue( $value, false, true );
        error_log( $key . ' = (' . gettype( $v ) . ') ' . $v );
        $this->$key = $this->formatvalue( $value, false, true );
    }
```

So it is not even about the keys or values....

Comment: 1) it clearly is the correct array as I print_r it before the loop and it is exactly what i want it to be 2) the problem happens in the foreach loop as no code is executed after it stops.

Comment: so you dont get that `error_log` to create a log inside your foreach? does that get executed?

Comment: @CodeGodie i do get it but only twice:
[26-Jan-2016 11:58:02 UTC] id = cus_7n5diIO2wjeaYX
[26-Jan-2016 11:58:02 UTC] object = customer

Comment: id say the problem lies in your `formatvalue()` func. Test each condition manually to see what it produces.

Comment: Yes, I can't see why it would you behave as you describe - but your description / analysis is lacking critical information - what appears your error_log *after* the 2 array keys?

Comment: var_dumps are also helpful. Try using that to see what its produced. `var_dump($object);`

Comment: @RyanVincent I added a screenshot of the entire error_Log - no error messages comes after these two iterations, it just stops and my browsers returns a chrome error (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Comment: @Lazhar can you provide a `var_dump` of the JSON response without transforming it into an array first? I want to see the actual response you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the function formatvalue.
This function doesn't accept object value.

Try this:

```
public function formatvalue( $value, $serialize = true, $nulltoemptystring = false ) {

    if( !isset( $value ) )
        return $nulltoemptystring ? '' : null;

    elseif( is_int( $value ) && $value == '0' )
        return 0;   

    elseif( is_array( $value ) || is_object( $value ) )
        return $serialize ? serialize( $value ) : $value;

    elseif( is_bool( $value ) )
        return $value ? 1 : 0;

    // you can replace by a simple trim
    return trim( $value );

    /*elseif( trim( $value ) === '' )
        return '';

    else
        return $value;*/
}
```

Comment: I tried and same thing happening, I added a screenshot of the entire error_Log

Comment: I also testing this function with a similar stripe object (not customer, but Subscription) and it works well. it just blocks in this case and i literally don't understand why since there is no error message :/